# record voice at voice call

Tags: iphone, audio, iphone-sdk-3.0, voice, voice-recording

In my app, i want to perform the following scenario.

- User inputs a number and press 'Call' button
- The Call button will forward the call to the callee and start recording the voice of the caller (both task will be coded in the same button click event)
- When user presses the 'End' button, call and recording both will be stopped.
- Then the just recorded audio will be played (though it is one sided communication)

I want to make this app for iPhone 3. Is it possible to make this app?

Answer (score 1):

I have thought of doing the same. You cannot record a call.

Comment: Thanks.But I don't want to record the call. Instead at the time of call, i also want to record the sound of the environment. It is an alternative way. I can record one sided speech by this way. I hope you understand now.

Comment: All applications that allow recording in the background (including apples own Voice Memo's) are closed. One reason is that the microphone is being used by the phone for the call. I also assume that all hardware is being used for the phone cal as well. Again my answers stands. You cannot make a call and record anything.